# Segmentation fault. Occured in an array element assignment, but now in printf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

(Update: Problem solved. It all came down to a stupid typo on my part, causing me to write the wrong part of memory, which in turn caused some pointer to point to someplace that was off limits.)

So, I'm taking a course that involves some programming, and we've essentially been thrown in the deep in of the C pool. I've programmed in other languages before, so it's not all new, but I don't have a solid set of tools to debug my code when the proverbial shit hits the fan.

I had, essentially, the following

```
int nParticles = 32;
int nSteps = 10000;
double u[nParticles], v[nParticles];

for (i = 0; i < nSteps; i++) {
...
    for (j = 0; j < nParticles; j++) {
        u[j] = 0.001 * v[j];
    }
...
}
```

as one part of a bigger program, and I was getting segmentation fault. In order to pinpoint the problem, I added a bunch of

```
printf("foo\n");
```

and eventually it turned out that I got to step `i = 209`, and particle `j = 31` before the segmentation fault occured.

After a bit of googling, I realised there's a tool called `gdb`, and with the extra `printf`s in there, doing `bt` in `gdb` tells me that now it's `printf` that segfaulting. Keep in mind though, I got segfaults before adding the diagnostic printfs as well.

This doesn't make much sense to me. How do I proceed from here?

---

Update:

`valgrind` gives me the following

```
==18267== Invalid read of size 8
==18267==    at 0x400EA6: main (in [path redacted])
==18267==  Address 0x7ff001000 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18267== 
==18267== 
==18267== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18267==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FF001000
==18267==    at 0x400EA6: main (in [path redacted])
==18267==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==18267==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==18267==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==18267==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==18267==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==18267== 
==18267== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18267==     in use at exit: 1,136 bytes in 2 blocks
==18267==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 0 frees, 1,136 bytes allocated
==18267== 
==18267== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18267==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18267==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18267==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18267==    still reachable: 1,136 bytes in 2 blocks
==18267==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18267== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==18267== 
==18267== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==18267== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I don't know what that means.

---

Update:

I tried commenting out the array assignment that initially caused the segfault. When I do that, but leave most of the diagnostic printfs in, I get a segfault at `i = 207` instead.

Update:

Problem solved. In the outer loop (where `i` is the counter, representing time steps), I had a couple of inner loops (all of which reused `j` as a counter, iterating over a bunch of particles). In one of the inner loops (*not the one that segfaulted*, though), I was accidentaly assigning values to `E[i]` where `E` is an array of `nParticles` size, so I was running way out of bounds. Fixing this stops the segfault from happening.

So, it all came down to a silly silly typo on my part.

---

Update:

I spoke to my brother, and he explained the problem in a way that at least satisfies my limited understanding of the situation.

By accidentaly writing things in `E` way beyond the end of that array, I probably overwrote the pointers associated with my other arrays, and then when I go to access those other arrays, I try to access memory that's not mine, and I get a segfault.

Thank you all so much for helping me out and putting up with my lack of knowledge!

Comment: look like some memory problem, mustlikely tring to write to mad memory place
download valgrind and post its output
hope you use linux, just "sudo apt-get install valgrind"

Comment: +1 for actually attempting some debugging; something that is rarer than a rightfold-project-completion these days.

Comment: 'However, I'm curious as to why the error occured where it did' - undefined behaviour.  Luckily, you didn't get the nasal demons this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This got too long for a comment, but is not a complete answer. It's impossible to tell why your program dies without seeing a minimal example of the code.

`printf` normally segfaults for one of three reasons: Either

1. you are passing it a parameter it can't access (for instance a `char *` that does not point to correctly allocated memory containing a zero terminated string), or
2. you've run out of stack space (stack overflow) due to too much recursion, or
3. you have corrupted the heap by writing beyond a dynamic memory allocation.

My advice would be:

1. Compile your program with the `-Wall` option. Fix every warning, and understand why the warning occurs rather than just hiding the problem. Compiling with `-Wall` is a good habit to get into, and finds a large number of errors.
2. Download `valgrind` and run your program in `valgrind`. This will catch a lot of stuff.
3. Learn to use `gdb`. Tutorial [here](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbtoc.html).
4. Comment or `#if` out large chunks of your program until you come down to the simplest case that does not error. Add bits back in and find out what the issue is.

Comment: The specific printf that fails is ``printf("Loop 2, iteration %i\n", j);``, which I believe is fine? As for compiling, I'm just running ``make`` and stuff happens; it's essentially a black box for me. How would I add the ``-Wall`` option to that?

Comment: If your makefile has been written helpfully, `make CFLAGS="-Wall"` should help. Else look in the makefile and find out where it calls `gcc` and add `-Wall` as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

See these kind of errors mostly happens when the stack is corrupted.

please check if you have some where crossed the boundaries of an array(specifically local arrays)

Comment: I have arrays ``double a[nParticles]`` and I run my loops ``for (i=0;i < nParticles; i++)``... should be fine, right?

Comment: @gibson Debug test: Add `static` -- >`static double u[nParticles], v[nParticles];`, If problem goes away, likely a stack issue.  if remains, likely somewhere else.

Comment: Trying to compile, I get ``error: storage size of 'u' isn't constant``.

Comment: @gibson Sorry, thought `10000` was the array size and not `32`, so array size/location is not likely the issue.  IAC, suggest posting more of the code.